# Is proportion also a probability?

Tags: probability

Assume I ask the following question:

79% of the population in a city is insured. If we sample 100 random people what is the probability that more than 68 people will be insured?

Is not 79% a probability of the population?

Thanks

Comment: Use the binomial distribution.

Comment: The probability for a randomly chosen person to be injured is in fact $0.79$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability $p$ that a given person selected at random is insured is $\frac{79}{100} = 0.79$. The probability $q=1-p$ that a given person selected at random is not insured is $0.21$.

If you sample that population, you expect the same probabilities to hold in the sample. You can find the estimated probability $P(x>68)$ that strictly more than $68$ are insured by using the principle of the binomial distribution. (Here, $x$ denotes the number in the sample that are insured).

The probability that you have exactly $69$ insured is $\binom{100}{69}(0.79)^{69}(0.21)^{31}$

The probability that you have exactly $70$ insured is $\binom{100}{70}(0.79)^{70}(0.21)^{30}$

and so forth, all the way up to $100$.

You have to sum all those up and you get a series sum $\displaystyle P(x>68) = \sum_{r=69}^{100} \binom{100}{r}(0.79)^r(0.21)^{100-r}$ that's not easy to work out.

(Wolfram Alpha calculates this as: $P(x>68) = 0.993272041190099999175030261706654837774833024902547696645...$, and you can see the expression worked out here: [Wolfram Alpha calculation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28binom%28100%2Cr%29%280.79%5Er%29%280.21%5E%28100-r%29%29%2C%20r%3D%2069%20to%20100))

Even though that gives you an exact answer, it's clearly not the easy way to do this (by hand).

The easier (and likely intended) way is for you to approximate the binomial using the normal distribution.

Here, $n = 100, p = 0.79, q = 0.21$. Since $np = 79$ and $nq=21$, and these are both greater than $5$, it is permissible to use the approximation.

The mean number insured in the sample $\bar x = np = 79$

The standard deviation $\sigma$ is $\sqrt{npq} \approx 4.073$

You are asked to find the probability that greater than $68$ are insured. Technically, you need to apply a continuity correction of $0.5$ (half) when you approximate a discrete distribution by a continuous one. So instead of finding $P(x > 68)$, you need to find $P(x > 68.5)$. It doesn't matter much here (numerically), but it's the proper way to do it.

Work out the $z$-score. That's $\displaystyle z = \frac{x- \bar x}{\sigma} \approx -2.578$.

If you now sketch a normal curve (to be sure of the area you need) and look up a table of values or use an online calculator, you will find that the probability that you require is $P(x>68.5) \approx 0.995$, which is about $99.5 \%$.

Comment: For completeness, the true value is $0.993$, so the normal approximation has just $0.2\%$ error.

Comment: Thanks, I'll edit the answer with the Wolfram Alpha link.

Comment: Thanks...I can also use p^ - p / sqrt(p(1-p)/n) to find P(X>68)...Z score for proportion

Comment: @MohammadRahman Yes, it will work out the same way because the methods are equivalent.